# Cómo saber si un punto esta dentro de un triángulo?

Tags: unity3d

Cómo detectar si un punto P se encuentra dentro del área del triángulo definida por los vertices ABC?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @huse, bienvenid@ a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Sea d el segmento ab.
d = b - a;

//Sea e el segmento ac.
e = c - a;


//Variable de ponderación a~b
w1 = (e.x * (a.y - p.y) + e.y * (p.x - a.x)) / (d.x * e.y - d.y * e.x);

//Variable de ponderación a~c
w2 = (p.y - a.y - w1 * d.y) / e.y;

//El punto p se encuentra dentro del triángulo
//si se cumplen las 3 condiciones:
if ((w1 >= 0.0) && (w2 >= 0.0) && ((w1 + w2) <= 1.0))
{
    //Punto dentro del triángulo
}
else
{
     //Punto fuera del triángulo
}
```

Fuente:

https://huse360.home.blog/2019/12/14/como-saber-si-un-punto-esta-dentro-de-un-triangulo/

https://youtu.be/WaYS1gEXEFE